# Can't get useful location from -mouseDown:event

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, events, macos, mouse

**Complete rewrite**

I now reproduced the issue I had posted about previously in a trivial sample project, and so I have absolutely *no* idea what I could be doing wrong. Here's what I'm now doing.

1. Create a new vanilla Cocoa Application (no Core Data, not document-based)
2. Add a class named "MyImageView.m", no header
3. Replace the contents of MyImageView.m with:

   ```
   @interface MyImageView :NSImageView {} @end


   @implementation MyImageView
   - (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
       NSLog( @"mouse down event: %@", event );
       NSPoint point = [event locationInWindow];
       NSLog( @"mouseDown location: (%d,%d)", point.x, point.y );
   }
   @end
   ```
4. Open MainMenu.xib in Interface Builder
5. Drag an Image Well onto your window
6. Change its class to `MyImageView`
7. Save everything and run
8. Click anywhere on the Image Well

I then see the message below on the console:

`2011-01-01 13:58:12.351 TestApp[1167:903] mouse down event: NSEvent: type=LMouseDown loc=(237,242) time=2033.7 flags=0x100 win=0x0 winNum=573 ctxt=0x0 evNum=286 click=1 buttonNumber=0 pressure=1`

`2011-01-01 13:58:12.353 TestApp[1167:903] mouseDown location: (-2057547688,16)`

Why is "loc" in the string representation of NSEvent correct, but `-locationInWindow` is so obviously wrong? What could I possibly do that would result in such trivial code being wrong?

I already restarted my system in case that might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two elements of `NSPoint` are floating point numbers, so it's your NSLog statement that's wrong, not the values that are being returned. You need to make sure the type in the format string matches the type of the variables, which you can do with casts:

This will work:

```
NSLog( @"mouseDown location: (%d,%d)", (int) point.x, (int) point.y );
```

As will this:

```
NSLog( @"mouseDown location: (%f,%f)", (float) point.x, (float) point.y );
```

Whether NSPoint contains 32-bit or 64-bit floating point varies between OS versions and systems. It might be worth using the built in point-to-string function:

```
NSLog( @"mouseDown location: %@", NSStringFromPoint(point) );
```

(Note that when actually doing maths and comparisons will work fine automatically without inserting casts. It's only NSLog that needs help getting this right.)

Comment: Note that casting `CGFloat` values to `int` values will lose the fractional portion, so if the user clicked on (20.3, 5.5), you will only see “(20,5)”.